# Rearranging a list of activities based on time data

Tags: r

In my data frame, there are two types of corresponding activities: A and B (Image 1). Based on the `Time` column, I want to arrange those activities to make them look like Image 2, listing all activities in one column and the subsequent activity in the next. How should I proceed?

[image]

[image: Output]

```
Type <-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
Activity <-c("Eating","Working","Playing","Awakening","Watching TV","Playing","Awakening","Working","Eating")
Time <-c("07:45:35","08:00:00","16:30:00","07:12:00","07:45:15","06:30:15","06:10:35","08:10:25","07:50:05")
df<- data.frame(Type,Activity,Time)
df
```

````
Type <-c("A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B")
Activity <-c("Eating","Working","Playing","Awakening","Watching TV","Playing","Awakening","Working","Eating")
Time<-c(07.45,08.00,16.30,07.12,07.45,06.30,06.10,08.10,07.50)
df<- data.frame(Type,Activity,Time)

str(df)

xa = df$Time[1:4]
ya = df$Activity[1:4]
za = df$Type[1:4]

nde<-fevent <- nevent <- c()
while(length(ya)>0) {
  i <- which.min(xa)
  fevent <- c(fevent,ya[i])
  nde <- c(nde,za[i])
  xa <- xa[-i]
  ya <- ya[-i]
  za <- za[-i]
  j <- which.min(xa)
  nevent <- c(nevent,ya[j])
}
outa <- data.frame(nde = nde[1:length(nevent)],fevent = fevent[1:length(nevent)],nevent)

xb = df$Time[5:9]
yb = df$Activity[5:9]
zb = df$Type[5:9]

nde<-fevent <- nevent <- c()
while(length(yb)>0) {
  i <- which.min(xb)
  fevent <- c(fevent,yb[i])
  nde <- c(nde,zb[i])
  xb <- xb[-i]
  yb <- yb[-i]
  zb <- zb[-i]
  j <- which.min(xb)
  nevent <- c(nevent,yb[j])
}
outb <- data.frame(nde = nde[1:length(nevent)],fevent = fevent[1:length(nevent)],nevent)

out <- bind_rows(outa,outb)
names(out) <- c("Type", "Event", "Next_Event")

out ```
````

Comment: At the moment it appears you expect us to redo your data entry. That’s generally going to result in the question being ignored. Learn to post [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

Turn the `Time` column to `POSIXct`, `arrange` it by `Type` and `Time` and  for each `Type` use `lead` to get next activity and remove `NA` rows.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(Time = as.POSIXct(Time, format = '%T')) %>%
  arrange(Type, Time) %>%
  group_by(Type) %>%
  mutate(Next_Activity = lead(Activity)) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  select(-Time)

#  Type  Activity    Next_Activity
#  <chr> <chr>       <chr>        
#1 A     Awakening   Eating       
#2 A     Eating      Working      
#3 A     Working     Playing      
#4 B     Awakening   Playing      
#5 B     Playing     Watching TV  
#6 B     Watching TV Eating       
#7 B     Eating      Working
```

Comment: Output is OK. but I try using while loop, Do you have any idea about how to modify my R code?